# ¿Cómo puedo actualizar las reglas de seguridad firebase?

Tags: firebase

Intento consultar datos con un botón pero en la consola del navegador me aparece éste error:

```
core.js:4081 ERROR Error: permission_denied at /contacts: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.
```

en las reglas lo tengo así:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
       allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(2021, 8, 14);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

como dice en la primer respuesta, esto es totalmente inseguro, para poder hacer pruebas en mi opinión esta bien, pero tendrías que asegurarte de que los usuarios puedan leer y escribir documentos después de haberse loguado, para poder hacer pruebas puedes asignar esta configuración:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
       allow read, write: true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Deberías de agregar detalles a tu respuesta indicando los elementos mas importantes

Answer (score -1):

En firebase se pueden habilitar las reglas de la base de datos para que cualquiera que tenga acceso a la misma pueda utilizarlo, **pero esto es inseguro**

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Si es para pruebas podés usarlo, pero repito, es **INSEGURO**

Lo que estaría bien es plantear una regla de seguridad, por ejemplo, que solo aquellos logueados en tu sistema puedan usarla.

Comment: ya lo probé pero no funcionó

Comment: no sé si sea del código del proyecto de angular pero no creo

Comment: Si te tira ese error se me hace extraño que sea el código de angular. Ojo que cada vez que haces un deploy en el hosting se te cambia las reglas, asegurate de tener las reglas por las dudas. También acordate que estas reglas solo funcionan para la bd cloud firestore. Si necesitas para la realtime son otras.